# odp.net ora-12154:TNS:Could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle

I am trying to create entity fm on asp.net MVC 5 with existing oracle database.I installed Oracle.ManageDataAccess & Entity client from nuget pm. But I am still getting this error when try to create entity framwork using ADO.NET.

```
TNS:Could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

Here is I have done in web.config with related Oracle Client and connectionString:

```
     <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <settings>
        <setting name="TNS_ADMIN" value="C:\app\tcetin\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN" />
      </settings>
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="SptsDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=******)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=dedicated)(SERVICE_NAME=*****)))" />
      </dataSources>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="OracleDbContext" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="User Id=****;Password=*****;Data Source=SptsDataSource" /> 
  </connectionStrings>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is your problem, but you are referencing a TNS_ADMIN, but then specifying your datasource directly. You shouldn't need the TNS_ADMIN part when specifying the datasource directly. My guess is your datasource definition isn't quite right.